# No data written to xml file

Tags: vb.net, xmlwriter

I have a datagridview and it is bound to a Dataset.  I enter data in the grid, in the UI and then click a button to write the xml.  When the xml is written, all I get is this;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RoboDataSet/>
```

No data, so I am definitely not understanding something.  My datagridview name is datagridview2, in the properties for the datagridview, Datasource says RoboDataSet

Here is my code;

```
 Private Sub WriteXmlToFile(RoboDataSet As DataSet)
    If RoboDataSet Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("The DataSet does not exist.")
        Return
    End If
    For Each t As DataTable In RoboDataSet.Tables
        MessageBox.Show(t.Rows.Count.ToString)
    Next
    Dim filename As String = "c:\data\write4.xml"
    Using Stream As New System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create)
        RoboDataSet.WriteXml(Stream)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Please let me know if I need to supply other information
Thank You

Comment: Does the `MessageBox.Show(t.Rows.Count.ToString)` line show anything?

Comment: line never appears

Comment: In that case, there are no datatables in the dataset passed to the Sub, which gives you something to investigate.